# sending form data to email with php

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I wrote a php page that send the form data to my email.
The problem is that when the user click on submit, he automatically moved to a **blank** php page. I want that instead of moving to a blank php page, the user stay on the same page and instead of the form fields, he see a message like "thank you for contacting us". How can I do this? and how can I style this message?

In addition, all the form data appears on the email subject (not in the body of the message). there is any way to change it?

Here is the PHP:

```
<?php

    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set("display_errors", "On");

    $subject="Message from Web";
    $sender=$_POST["user-name"];
    $senderEmail=$_POST["email"];
    $senderPhone=$_POST["phone"];
    $senderCompany=$_POST["company"];
    $message=$_POST["message"];

    $mailBody="Name: $sender\nEmail: $senderEmail\nPhone: $senderPhone\nCompany: $senderCompany\n\n$message";

    mail('mymail@gmail.com', $mailBody, $sender);

    $thankYou="<p>Thank you! Your message has been sent.</p>";

?>
```

Comment: Can you give us some code?

Comment: I would suggest you look at using ajax to send the data to your php. To add the subject into the body of your email we would need to see your php code to know how you have the email set out. We can't work blind. I'm going to assume this php code is a copy/paste since you don't know how to insert variables/data to the body of the email.

Comment: I edited the message. I prefer not using AJAX because I don't know how to use it.

Comment: To add the subject into the body of the email you can add ` $subject` into `$mailBody` for example: `$mailBody="Name: $sender\nEmail: $senderEmail\nPhone: $senderPhone\nCompany: $senderCompany\n$subject\n\n$message";` As for sending the form data to PHP, you asked for suggestions on how to do that without pushing the user to that PHP page. Well Ajax will do that. This is where you will have to learn rather than copy/paste If you have no interest in learning then I recommend you hire a developer.

Comment: Sidenote: Check your Spam because your `$sender` in your header should be an Email, and not someone's name.

Comment: Not knowing AJAX should not be the reason for not trying to use it. Even the jQuery AJAX shorthand can make life easier.

Comment: Ever heard of echo? `echo $thankYou;` or a header to redirect to a thank you page?

Comment: Can you please explain how to do it with echo please?
Thanks

Comment: *"and how can I style this message?"* - Look up "CSS tutorial".

Comment: I suggest you learn how to use PHP before trying anything like emailing scripts. This could turn out very bad for you. If you don't validate your email script you may find your contact form being used to spam inboxes.

Comment: I know how to use CSS very well. I don't know how to select a PHP element.

Comment: `echo "<div id=\"ID\" class=\"some_class\">Hello world!</div>";`

Comment: If you want to use PHP then start with the basic stuff, don't jump to emailing forms. If you host this on your website `anyone` could use your site to send spam/malicious emails with no trace of who sent it, you have no validation on the data.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="to-e-mail">
<input type="text" name="subject">
<textarea name="message">
</textarea>
<input type="submit" value="send">
</form>
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
$headers = 'From: sender@mail.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($_POST['to-e-mail'],$_POST['subject'],$_POST['message'],$headers);
print 'thank you for contacting us';
}

?>
```

Very simple example how to send mail with php. 
Please check the security requirements.